# Fuse 3D-Points in Bundle Adjustment?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computer-science, computer-vision

I'm actually implementing my own Pose-Estimation/- and -Refinement pipeline. For this purpose I use one moving mono-camera. Then I take the consecutive images to estimate the pose and triangulate the points (nothing special). In the last step I refine the poses and 3D-points with a bundle adjustment approach.

Generating 3D points with triangulation from consecutive image pairs will give me multiple estimations for one real-world 3D point. In fact, all the estimations refer to the same point. For my understanding, these estimations of the same 3D-points have to be fused in some way. Otherwise the poses were not linked anymore through a common point (see also image below). Further, looking at the equation for the re-projection error in different publications:

[image: Core equation Bundle Adjustment]

turns out, that 3D point (vector a) is only related to **j** and not to the cameraindex **i**.

[image: Stolen from: SBA: A Software Package for Generic Sparse Bundle Adjustment, MANOLIS I. A. LOURAKIS and ANTONIS A. ARGYROS]

Do I understand that right or do I have to use a different set of 3D points for each camera view? Suppose I've to merge the 3D points, is there any preferable strategy?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I know, there are already countless implementations for BA. I want to use it for further development...

Comment: Hi. This is more of a question for one of these SE sites, you'll probably have better luck there: [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/) or even [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: About reprojection error: the way I understand it, the vectors `a[j]` represent actual points in 3D space (the estimated 3D coords of the black dots) - in "world space"; this is why they are independent of the camera index `i` - and why there's only one set of points. `Q(a[j], b[i])` then (re)projects those points back onto each view [i]. Then, for each view, you compare the original point `x` (from the image) with the result of Q by finding the distance between them in "camera space" - you are adjusting the estimate and the camera positions, by minimizing the error in camera space.

Comment: As for your other question - and I'm guessing here - you can probably just do an average of several estimates (for the same 3D point) to get a single "merged" point  (just do vector sum, and scale by inverse of the number of estimates), and use that as the initial guess for `a[j]`, then minimize the error from there.

Comment: At first, thanks for your reply and the recommendations to further sites. About the reprojection error: I'm totally conform with your explanation. That's exactly how I understood it so far. 

For now I average the 3D-points, that derived from one common physical point. It seems to be a fair method to do this, but I still wonder why nobody mentioned this step in the publications. Maybe it's just to obvious...

Thanks again for your answers. I will leave this thread open until I finished my implementation and testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, everything works now as expected and the results seem to be correct. I took the **average of all 3D-Point belonging to one physical point**. Therefore this question should be considered as answered.

Just a point for further investigation: Taking the average may not be a really robust way. It would be useful to implement something like an outlier control. But this was not part of the question at core.